# Difference between return Task and await Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

Is there any difference between:

```
    public async Task Stop()
    {
        //some Code
        await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
    }
```

and

```
    public Task Stop()
    {
        //some Code
        return semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
    }
```

Which approach is preferred and why?