# Is there any difference between `return SomeFuncAsync()` and `await SomeFuncAsync(); return;`?

Tags: c#, async-await

Simply, are these two functions functionally exactly the same?

```
async Task SomeFuncAsync()
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
}

async Task Foo1()
{
  await BarAsync();
  return SomeFuncAsync();
}

async Task Foo2()
{
  await BarAsync();
  await SomeFuncAsync();
}
```

If not, what is the difference?

(Note this is slightly different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122450/difference-between-return-task-and-await-task) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033150/any-difference-between-await-task-run-return-and-return-task-run) because I'm not considering removing `async` from my function signature. If this is a duplicate, please link and I'll delete.)

Comment: In the second version you are not returning the results of `SomeFuncAsyn()`, so the first instance would return a `Task` where as the second version would return a Task<T> where T = the return type of `SomeFuncAsync()`

Comment: Ah, I actually meant Task with no return value `Task` rather than `Task<>`. I guess I should have specified that.

Comment: I'd think the exception propagation would differ.

Comment: @RyanWilson what is there to return?

Comment: @RyanWilson Per your original comment, now both definitively return `Task` with no generic parameter (in the previous version, it was ambiguous and determined by the definition of `SomeFuncAsync`, which wasn't provided.

Comment: Since everything returns a Task, there's no difference in your situation.

Comment: The first `Foo1` returns a task wrapped in a task. That is because `async Task` signature will wrap the result in a Task as the return value.

Comment: @SelmanGenç There's your answer, it returns a `Task`

Comment: Your edit wont compile… `Since 'Program.Foo1()' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task<T>'`

Comment: Good catch @RandRandom! I just assumed it would work since `Task<T>` inherits from `Task`, so returning a `Task<T>` should be fine in the above case (even with `T = Task`). I guess there's logic to prevent that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `Foo1` returns a task wrapped in a task.

```
async Task Foo1()
{
  await BarAsync();
  return SomeFuncAsync();
}
```

That is because `async Task` signature will wrap the result in a `Task` as the return value. This happens because you are not awaiting the result. The proper return type in the signature though should be `Task<Task>`, not `Task>` because the code is returning something (in this case a Task).

```
async Task<Task> Foo1()
{
  await BarAsync();
  return SomeFuncAsync();
}
```

---

Once you correct the return type on this method the difference between it and the next method becomes more obvious. The first one returns a `Task` wrapped in a `Task` and the next one just returns a `Task`.

Comment: actually, the code doesn't compile. saying "return type is void"

Comment: I never wana see that thing… consuming it is ugyl `var taskOfFoo1 = await Foo1(); await taskOfFoo1;`

Comment: @RandRandom - maybe there is use case for it but I have not run across one yet.

Comment: how does this answer "what is the difference?" ?

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense if it doesn't compile :P I'd delete it if I could, but SO wants me to keep it around to educate the masses, apparently.